# Displaying information/advertise between transition of two forms in lwuit

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I am making one application on mobile using Lwuit/java-me. I am having the problem in implementing an advertise/information form between the transaction of two forms. the advertise/information screen should stay for 5 seconds only and then the next subsequent screen should display automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You must show a `Dialog` between `Forms`. Put to this `Dialog` a timeout using `setTimeout` method, and it will dispose automatically

Answer (score 2):

Did you use the GUI builder? How are you showing forms?

A simple way is to create an Ad Form with all the details and just show it instead of showing the next form (give it the actual next form when constructing it).

Within the Ad form register an animation that measures the 5 seconds to move to the next form:

```
adForm.registerAnimation(new Animation() {
    public void paint(...) { 
        // empty
    }
    public boolean animate() {
         if(fiveSecondsPasssed) {
             showNextForm();
         }
         return false;
    }
});
```